# receiving calls/text if mobile data is off

Tags: mobile-data

when I travel where only my phone network is available, I want to turn my data to off so I don't get any updates. If i do that can I still receive calls and texts from others?

Comment: This is a duplicate probably

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

Turning Data Off only disconnects Internet connection. It doesnt effect Calls/Texts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will still be able to send/receive phone calls and texts. If you are using any messaging apps that rely on internet then those won't work Your *"radio"* or *"modem"* is what controls the phone and texting. You just won't have any internet.